# passing the index value of the selected value from the spinner to asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, spinner

In the registration process, when the user select the title from the spinner then its array index values should be automatically select and send to the asynctask. I want to send the array index value (position) as well in the below shown code.

```
new RegisterAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(TitleName,CountryName);
```

original value of the position is inside the `onItemSelected()`, I want to know how to pass it to the `onclick()`

this is my java code

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
private String[] states, states1;
private Spinner countrySP, titleSP;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerTitle);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

        states = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_array);
        states1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_array);

        titleSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerTitle);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
        dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        titleSP.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        countrySP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.registerCountry);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states1);
        dataAdapter1
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        countrySP.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {


                    String TitleName = titleSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String CountryName = countrySP.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String position = String.valueOf(titleSP.getSelectedItemPosition());
                String position = String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition()); //Duplicate local variable position

                                    new RegisterAsyncTask(
                                            getApplicationContext()).execute(
                                                    TitleName,
                                                    CountryName, position);

                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Asynctask started",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }

            }
        });


    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    //check which spinner triggered the listener
    switch (parent.getId()) {
    //country spinner
    case R.id.registerTitle:
        //make sure the country was already selected during the onCreate
        String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_array);
        String selectedTitle = titles[position];  
        System.out.println("title = " + position );

    case R.id.registerCountry:
        //make sure the country was already selected during the onCreate
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.country_array);
        String selectedCountry = countries[position];  
        System.out.println("country = " + position );
    }

}




    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    }

}
```

My title.xml inside values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title_prompt">Choose the title</string>
    <string-array name="title_array">
        <item>Mr</item>
        <item>Mrs</item>
        <item>Miss</item>
        <item>Dr</item>
        <item>Rev</item>
        <item>Ms</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: what do you expect to get from this `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` and what exactly do you need? selected item position?

Comment: to select the item position, im getting position value in String selectedTitle = titles[position]; ------- i want to know how to pass the index value of the position to onCreate()

Comment: onCreate()?, honestly i don't understand what you need!

Comment: sry it should be onClick(), so i can pass the index value position to RegisterAsyncTask. currently im passing TitleName, same as that i want to pass the title position. Did u get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use   [getSelectedItemPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29) to get selected item position from Spinner on Button click as:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       String TitleName = titleSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
       String CountryName = countrySP.getSelectedItem().toString();
       String position=String.valueOf(titleSP.getSelectedItemPosition());
       // pass position to RegisterAsyncTask
       new RegisterAsyncTask(
         getApplicationContext()).execute(TitleName,CountryName,position);

  }
```

Comment: @JohnDavid :I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: what happens when I have to pass the country ID as well? I can't use 2 position ryt?

Comment: @JohnDavid: no issue pass it in same way as currently passing `titleSP`

Comment: @JohnDavid: do it as `String positionCountry=String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition());....execute(TitleName,CountryName,position,positionCountry)`

Comment: Im getting Duplicate local variable position under the position, String position=String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition());

Comment: @JohnDavid: create new variable as `String positioncountrySP=String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition());` ans pass `positioncountrySP` as `new RegisterAsyncTask(
         getApplicationContext()).execute(TitleName,CountryName,position,positioncountrySP);`

Comment: how can i use positioncountrySP inside onItemSelected(); --- its allowing only to use position

Comment: @JohnDavid: you want to pass `positionCountry` value to `RegisterAsyncTask` or want to access inside `onItemSelected` ? if you want to access inside `onItemSelected` then use again `positionCountry=String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition());` line in `onItemSelected`

Comment: inside onItemSelected(), im suppose to use the position, if not it wont give the index value. then if i use the position in RegisterAsyncTask, it gives Duplicate local variable position error.

Comment: @JohnDavid: please update your code with latest code

Comment: @JohnDavid: what happening when you are using ` String positionSP = String.valueOf(countrySP.getSelectedItemPosition());new RegisterAsyncTask(
                                            getApplicationContext()).execute(
                                                    TitleName,
                                                    CountryName, position,positionSP);`  ?

Comment: then it wont get the index value from onItemSelected(). i cant change String selectedCountry = countries[position]; >  position to anything else (eg. positionSP)

Comment: @JohnDavid: dear not need to change `onItemSelected` code just use code as i have suggest in onClick method and tell me what issue you are getting

Comment: ρяσѕρєя K that works now, my bad i have made a small mistake in doInBackground(). once again thnx alot

Answer (score 1):

yes now i get it,
you need to do something like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

try {


String TitleName = titleSP.getSelectedItem().toString();
String CountryName = countrySP.getSelectedItem().toString();
String selectedPos=Integer.toString(titleSP.getSelectedItemPosition()); // or countrySP if u need it to


                new RegisterAsyncTask(
                        getApplicationContext()).execute(
                                TitleName,
                                CountryName, selectedPos);
:
:
```

now you have to modify `RegisterAsyncTask` doInBackground():

```
... doInBackground(String... params){
//params[0] is TitleName
//params[1] is CountryName
//params[2] is selectedPos
:
:
}
```

Comment: thnx but I got the answer before u post ur answer.

Comment: @JohnDavid yup, i saw that, i was trying to understand what you need :)